# Alignment of div using flex

Tags: flexbox

I have one parent div which height is 450px. And 3 child div which height is 150px each. i want to align this 3 div using flex. and the position is 1div: left-corner, 2div:center, 3div:bottom-right.
give me the solution using only css flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
display:'flex',
height:'450px',
justifyContent:'space-between'
```

**Edit**

```
  <div
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      height: "450px",
      flexDirection: "column",
    }}
  >
    {/* top  */}

    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ flex: "0 0 25%", border: "1px solid" }}>
        <h1>left</h1>
      </div>
      <div style={{ flex: "0 0 25%", border: "1px solid" }}>
        <h1>center</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    {/* bottom  */}
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent:'flex-end'
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          flex: "0 0 50%",
          border: "1px solid",
        }}
      >
        <h1>bottom right</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanx .. but I want 1 and 2 div in  row with 1 div in left corner and 2 in center.. and 3 div in next row with bottom right corner.

Comment: Now i update @AdeshJadhav check it